# Sitecore WFFM 8.2 rev. 160801 is not storing data in reporting database

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8.2

I have installed Sitecore 8.2 rev. 160801 in my machine and worked on forms. On submission of form, I didn't get any error but the values are not stored in Database. In log also I didn't find any error.

I followed the post installation steps and ran the WFFM_Analytics.sql script on my reporting database.

Could you please someone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 1):

By default the WFFM data is stored in Mongo (in a collection called FormData). You should find your data there. If you want the data to be stored in SQL, you can change that by using anothor provider: https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/setting_up_web_forms/installing/use_a_custom_sql_provider_to_store_form_data

> In the Web Forms for Marketers module, you can use your own SQL Server
>   storage location, if, for example, you would like to store form data
>   in a different, more secure location.
>
> By default, the xDB data provider stores and exports data from the xDB
>   analyticsFormsDataProvider class. However, you can change the data
>   provider to a custom SQL Server database data provider, or to a
>   combined reporting and custom SQL Server database data provider